# How do I increase spacing between unit components in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx

I'm using `pgfplots` (version 1.12) with the `units` library.  When I create a unit label `\si{molecules \cm^{-2}}`, this turns up without any spacing between "molecules" and "cm".  When I use the same `\si{molecules \cm^{-2}}` in normal text, I *do* get appropriate spacing.  A MWE and a resulting image follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\begin{axis}[xlabel=quantity,x unit=\si{molecules \cm^{-2}}]%
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,3)};
\end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image: Lack of spacing]

How can I get some whitespace between "molecules" and "cm"?

Answer (score 1):

Define a new siunit for molecules, which should be done anyway. 
Then, let pgfplots send the unitpart to siunitx to let it take control of typesetting.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molecules}{molecules}
\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}}
\sisetup{per-mode=power}
\DeclareSIUnit{\molrate}{\molecules\per\centi\meter\squared}%for convenience
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=quantity,x unit=\molecules\per\centi\meter\squared]%
        \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,3)};
    \end{axis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

You can also define the whole thing as a unit for convenience and use that instead. Might save some typing and makes sure you work consistently.

Comment: Works — but does not address the question *why* the space is eaten when I'm using siunitx inside pgfplots, but the space appears when I use siunitx directly.

Comment: @gerrit I think in the original case, the question, the molecules part was somehow munged as the prefix. Not sure though, first time i ever used the library.